# Sharepoint Designer 2007: Adds server name on links

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

When I use Sharepoint Designer 2007 and create a link or a picture reference to something on the Sharepoint 2007 Standard Server, and I had used the slash (/) to indicate root, SharePoint Designer automatically adds the server name in the beginigng to the left of it (The complete URL). Is there an option or something to stop it from doing this?

Sometimes some links have the actual server name and others the alternate public name.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?  Where are you adding these links (controls, as HTML, etc.)? A specific example (code) would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Links to another page or site inside a content editor web part, for example. Some are in the navigation (menu), to point to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, and the easiest workaround is to use Javascript.  You can set your link to something like:

```
javascript:window.location='/Lists/SomeList/AllItems.aspx'
```

So in a link it would look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location='/Lists/SomeList/AllItems.aspx'">Wowee</a>
```

Comment: Sharepoint Designer automatically reformats the HTML and adds the hostname part. I guess that could work, but I was hoping for an option I need to toggle in the app.